# Angular2 nested routing

Tags: angular

I have a dashboard which has a link to the Profile page. When a user goes to Profile page it displays his profile, which has various sections e.g. basic information, portfolio, hobbies etc. Each section has a Add button clicking on which displays Add Section form (e.g Add Portfolio)

Dashboard url: `/dashboard/`

Profile url: `/dashboard/profile/`

Add Portfolio url: `/dashboard/profile/portfolio/new`

Edit Portfolio url: `/dashboard/profile/portfolio/edit/:id`

What I want is that when user clicks the Add Portfolio button it should display the Add Portfolio form just above the Portfolio list, without replacing the complete profile. Similarly when edit link corresponding to a portfolio record is clicked it should display Edit Portfolio form above the list.

I am very new to Angular2 routing and can do simple routing, but if I implement it above with my current approach, I end up with links which when clicked replaces whole contents of the Profile page, probably because it only has one router outlet.

Any help, probably a plunker demonstrating a above case would be highly appreciated.

Comment: so basically you have list of profiles under dashboard right, and each profile contains list of portfolio and you need 2 workspaces (edit and new) which going to contain list of portfolio - is it right ?

Answer (score 0):

The Add Portfolio form should be a part of the Portfolio page rather than it's own page (i.e. they shouldn't have separate URLs).

You could make the Add Portfolio form into it's own component, and set it as hidden initially. Assuming you make an `AddPortfolio` component with selector `add-portfolio`, then in the HTML for your Portfolio component you could have eg.

```
<add-portfolio [hidden]="hide"></add-portfolio>
```

Then in the `AddPortfolio` class you have a boolean field, `hide`, which is initially `true`, and is set to `false` on the Add button click.

Comment: Thank you Charonos for your reply. This is what I am doing currently, but this approach has a drawback, that if after clicking Add Portfolio button user clicks browser's back button then instead of the Add Portfolio form being closed he is redirected to the Dashboard page. So, I want the form to be hidden in case user clicks browser back button.

Comment: Ah, I see. There is a way to pass data to a route, so perhaps you can use this to re-initialize the profile with the correct information when the user clicks Add. I'm new to Angular 2 myself and am not familiar with the details, but I found [this example](https://yakovfain.com/2015/11/11/angular-2-passing-data-to-routes/).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have separated `url` for create and edit portfolio scenario i might offer you following url separtation:

Dashboard url: `/dashboard/view`  --> all profiles under dashboard

Profile url: `/dashboard/profile/`

Add Portfolio url: `/dashboard/profile/portfolio/new`

Edit Portfolio url: `/dashboard/profile/portfolio/edit/:id`

Your entry point file gonna have look like this:

#### App.ts

```
...
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/dashboard', component: DashboardRoutedComponent, name: 'Dashboard' }
])
export class App {  }
}
...
```

`DashboardRoutedComponent` - we going to name components which serve routing purposes like `RoutedComponent` in the end

#### App.html

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  providers: [ ...FORM_PROVIDERS ],
  directives: [ ...ROUTER_DIRECTIVES ],
  template: `
    <header>
    </header>

      <router-outlet></router-outlet>

    <footer>
    </footer>
  `
})
```

your `DashboardRoutedComponent` goint to define child routes

#### DashboardRoutedComponent.ts

```
@Component({
    selector:   'someSelectorDoesntMatter',
    template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>' -->that's why we name it routed component
    directives: [
        ROUTER_DIRECTIVES
    ]
})
@RouteConfig([
    {
        path: '/view',
        name: 'View',
        useAsDefault: true,
        component: DashboardViewComponent,  --> here you going to display list of profiles
        data: { name: 'View' }
    },
    {
        path: '/profile/...',  --> here we show that component going to have child routes
        name: 'Profile',
        component: ProfileRoutedComponent,
        data: { name: 'Profile' }
    }
])
export class DashboardRoutedComponent {}
```

`ProfileRoutedComponent` will have same structure for view\edit\new.

In order to have list of portfolio in new\edit scenarios they just going to share `some portfolio list component` and which will be re-render once new\edit portfolio component going to share same services to fetch data.

i will update answer with plunk

Comment: Thank you Kostia for your reply. Probably a plunker would be more helpful to understand it. I would like to add that Dashboard component have just few icons pointing to different features and one of the is Profile. When user clicks Profile icon he is taken to /dashboard/profile/ which displays profile and each section of profile has Add/Edit link, clicking on the link should not override the profile view but just show the form inline, but the url should change, so that when user click back button it should just close the Add/Edit form while keeping profile on the page.